# Show/hide a particular monitor in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, multiple-monitors

Is it possible to quickly hide what's on a particular monitor in Visual Studio? Similar to Norton Commander where you could easily hide left or right panel, I want to quickly hide all panels on one of the monitors to see behind them. Is it possible, maybe with a plugin?

Comment: Maybe if you think about this problem from a different perspective: [BossKey](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Boss-Key/boss-key.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. 
For that, you need **Visual Studio Professional** and **Productivity Power Tools** extension. (You can install it with VS2010 Extension Manager)

PPT allows **Floating Tab Wells**: You can dock floating document windows on a separate monitor just like tool windows.  There’s also an option now which allows you to open documents as floating by default.

Every Tab group has a minimize button. You can minimize the main window without minimize the tab floating panel, and vice-versa.

In my case, I have my main window at left and floating tab at right. If I want to see behind my right monitor, I just minimize the tab group only. With that I see the code at main window and whatever has behind the tab at right side.

For more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/10/document-well-2010-plus.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: But it is only for document tabs? On the second screen I have Solution Explorer, Unit Tests, Properties and Output. Can they be all put into a floating well?

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin Yes! Absolutely. My current configuration: 1° Monitor: Main Window (menus, toolbars and some code documents). 2° Monitor: Secondary window with others code documents, properties, solution explorer, etc). You can configure it as you like.

Comment: Tried it out. It's not ideal since there is no way to assign a keyboard shortcut, but it'll do, thanks.

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin If alt+space+n combination doesn't work, dont worry. Visual Studio 2012 has that option.

Comment: huh never knew you could do that. Still only works on VS main window, not on the tabbed well.

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin Sad to hear that. I'm using VS 2012 and I can do that with all windows.